# Python groupby result count frequency

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['one','one','two','two','three','three','three'],
                   'type':['current','saving','current','current','current','saving','credit']})
```

I would like to count the number of id which only has 'current'
something should like:

```
only_currnt_id_list = ['two']
```

Comment: why it should result with `two`?

Comment: Since only user "two" has only "current" type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by using `pd.crosstab`

```
df=pd.crosstab(df.id,df.type)
df.loc[df.sum(1)==df.current,].index.values[0]

Out[1065]: 'two'
```

or you can using `groupby` and `nunique`

```
df['unique']=df.groupby('id')['type'].transform('nunique')

df.loc[(df.unique==1)&(df.type=='current'),:].id.unique().tolist()


Out[1085]: ['two']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
L = df.groupby('id') \
      .filter(lambda x: (x['type'] == 'current').all() and 
                        (x['type'] == 'current').sum() == 1)['id'].tolist()
print (L)

['two']
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['one','one','two','three','three','three'],'type':['current','current','current','current','saving','credit']})
print (df)
      id     type
0    one  current
1    one  current
2    two  current
3  three  current
4  three   saving
5  three   credit
```

---

```
L = df.groupby('id') \
      .filter(lambda x: (x['type'] == 'current').all() and 
                        (x['type'] == 'current').sum() == 1)['id'].tolist()
print (L)
['two']

L = df.groupby('id') \
      .filter(lambda x: (x['type'] == 'current').all())['id'].unique().tolist()
print (L)
['one', 'two']
```

Comment: What is the `(x['type'] == 'current').sum() == 1` part for?

Comment: Hi jezrael, thanks for your answer, it works indeed. While what if the user 'two' has more than one 'current' type?

Comment: sorry, it means if need filter only `id` which have one value `current`. I add sample for better explain.

Comment: I add solution if need values of `id` if all values are only `current`

Answer (score 0):

Not using pure Pandas, but you could just use the `set` difference between all the IDs and IDs what have `type != 'current'`:

```
>>> set(df["id"]) - set(df["id"][df["type"] != "current"])
{2}
```